# Set syntax to diff in sublime text 2 when I do a git commit --verbose

Tags: git, syntax, sublimetext2

The first step I took was to setup git to use Sublime Text 2 as my editor.

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

This is getting Sublime Text 2 to open up every time I do a 'git commit --verbose', but how do I get Sublime Text 2 to automatically open up the COMMIT_EDITMSG file with the diff syntax already set?

I know that one solution is to set all plain text files to open with the diff syntax, but I don't want to do that because plain text files other than the ones coming from COMMIT_EDITMSG shouldn't have diff syntax.

Thank you very much for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible via a simple plugin that catches when files are being loaded and sets the syntax as appropriate based on the file name.

To do this, select `Tools > New Plugin...` from the menu, replace the sample code with the code below, then save it as a `py` file in the location that Sublime will default to (e.g. `diff_syntax_setter.py`):

```python
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class DiffListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_load(self, view):
        if view.file_name() is not None:
            if view.file_name().endswith("COMMIT_EDITMSG"):
                view.settings().set("syntax", 'Packages/Diff/Diff.tmLanguage')
```

Now every time a file is loaded that ends with the name `COMMIT_EDITMSG`, the syntax will automatically be set to the Diff syntax.

This plugin will also ***MOSTLY*** work with Sublime Text 3, although the location of the menu command was changed to `Tools > Developer > New Plugin...` instead.

The caveat here is that in Sublime Text 2, the startup of the editor includes the loading of all plugins prior to performing commands from the command line (such as opening a file)).

In Sublime Text 3, the startup is more streamlined in that the editor starts and becomes available while plugins are still being loaded. This makes for a faster startup since things aren't held up waiting for the plugins to load, but it means that the file has already been opened before the custom plugin has been loaded.

As such, while this works in Sublime Text 3, it will only work if Sublime was already running and won't work if the command causes Sublime to start up fresh.